# Docker - Waiting for Mongo to load before running create indexes script

Tags: mongodb, docker

I have a script that creates text indexes in MongoDB - however if i use it with my current Dockerfile (which in turn is being called in my docker-compose file), it results in an error as Mongo hasn't fully loaded.

I've seen `dependsOn` however that appears to be for a entire service. Also come across this https://github.com/ufoscout/docker-compose-wait/ however I'd like to avoid using it if there's something much simplier.

Has anyone solved this - wait for Mongo to load before `RUN`?

My dockerfile

```
FROM mongo:4
COPY ./scripts /scripts
RUN mongo<scripts/create-text-indexes
```

And docker-compose snippet:

```
dashboard-mongo:
    build:
      context: ./infrastructure
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: a-custom-mongo:SNAPSHOT
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    networks:
      default:
      cms:
        aliases:
          - dashboard-mongo
```

And the script I'm running looks like:

```
use customboard

print("---> Deleting existing indexes...");
db.test.dropIndexes();

print("---> Creating indexes...");
db.test.createIndex({
    "_id": "text",
    "code": "text"
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RUN mongo<scripts/create-text-indexes` this script will not work, remember `RUN` command is for installation and configuration not to interact with Database or start the process. you should start the process in CMD or entrypoint.

one way to use [offical image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) or [clone the offical](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo) repo and take the benefit from offical docker image entrypoint. why reinvent the wheel?

Wit offical image all you need

```
FROM mongo:4
COPY ./scripts /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Once you build and start the container the offical image will start the DB process and wait once it is able to handle connection then it will run the script.

**Initializing a fresh instance**

> When a container is started for the first time it will execute files
>   with extensions .sh and .js that are found in
>   /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d. Files will be executed in alphabetical
>   order. .js files will be executed by mongo using the database
>   specified by the MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE variable, if it is present, or
>   test otherwise. You may also switch databases within the .js script.

[docker mongo image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo)

Comment: Thanks - however I've added the script I'm running above - when I try to run this it doesnt execute. I've read it needs to be in a `.js` format. However that first line `use customboard` would surely break it?

Comment: using offical image, `MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE` will use this db by default,
This variable allows you to specify the name of a database to be used for creation scripts in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*.js (see Initializing a fresh instance below). MongoDB is fundamentally designed for "create on first use", so if you do not insert data with your JavaScript files, then no database is created.

Comment: BTW you can use DB using `db = db.getSiblingDB("customboard");` then `db.test.dropIndexes();`

Comment: Hey - yeah just came across that here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo
Will give that a go. Thanks

Comment: Worked! Appreciated!!